# How can I detect window destruction from the main thread?

Tags: windows, winapi

Typically, the window procedure for a "main" window class would call PostQuitMessage in response to a WM_DESTROY message.

I would prefer to have the main thread decide when it wants to terminate based on the lifespan of the window(s) it creates.  This way, whatever window class I choose to be the main window can have a generic window procedure that doesn't have PostQuitMessage in it.

```
while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);

    if(msg.hwnd == hWnd && msg.message == WM_DESTROY)
    {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
    }
}
```

The above is my attempt, but the WM_DESTROY message is never posted to the message queue, it seems to be internal to the window procedure.

Is there some way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a method that seems to do what I want.  I was inspired by http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/66508-peekmessage-and-wm-close/ by Valik to investigate subclassing.

First, I replace the Window Procedure of the window that I want to a special "PostQuitMessage" procedure.

```
Original_WindowProc = (WNDPROC)GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWL_WNDPROC);
SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)&WindowProc);
```

The window procedure looks like this:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg,  WPARAM wParam,  LPARAM lParam)
{
    if(uMsg == WM_DESTROY)
    {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
    }

    return CallWindowProc(Original_WindowProc, hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

This allows me to convert any window class (including system ones) into the main window for my application.

Comment: @Cody I'd recommend using [`SetWindowSubclass`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762102%28VS.85%29.aspx) and its friends to do your subclassing.

Comment: @David: Probably a better idea. The more general article on subclassing is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773183.aspx), which covers all of the techniques and their advantages/disadvantages. The biggest caveat about `SetWindowSubclass` is it's undocumented and (I believe) exported by numeral only in versions of Windows prior to XP. I remember successfully using it from my VB 6 days, but your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 5):

`WM_DESTROY` is being *sent* rather than *posted* which is why it never lands in the message queue. If it ends up in the `WndProc`, and it doesn't come through the message pump, what other explanation could there be?

Window handles are destroyed by calling `DestroyWindow` which, in turn, sends the `WM_DESTROY` message directly to the `WndProc`.

I think you will need to find some other way for your potential main windows to decide which one is the one that brings the curtain down when it is destroyed.

Comment: did this explanation help you understand the problem?

Comment: I think you meant `DestroyWindow()` rather than `DestroyWindowHandle()`.

Comment: I was really looking for insight into what "some other way" would be.  But your answer is worth an upvote.

Comment: @martin I didn't pick that up. It would have been hard without knowing more about what language, libraries etc. you used. Anyway your question was specifically if there was a way to achieve the decision taking in the message pump and I explained why that was not possible.

Comment: @David Hefferman: The message pump example was there merely to head-off "what do you have so far" comments. The title is detecting window destruction from the main thread (specifically without using PostQuitMessage in the WindowProc).

Comment: @martin It's the terminology that's got me a little confused. All of this happens in the main thread because all your windows have affinity with the main thread. I think you are saying that you want the decision taken by the code that decides which windows to create, but in a plain win32 app I don't know a convenient name for that!

Comment: @Martin Funny also that your answer calls `PostQuitMessage` in the `WindowProc`!

Comment: @David Hefferman, the point is that it's not the WindowProc of the original class.  The original class has no idea that it's the main window until the main thread designates it as such using subclassing.